# AWS SQS and Security Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-security-group

I wasn't able to find an option to attach security groups to AWS SQS instance. Why isn't it required? Is the queue secured only using the AWS credentials which are used to connect to the account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't include AWS SQS into your VPC. This is a fully managed service.

You can secure the SQS Queue with IAM roles. You need to give permission to whoever uses this queue to allow to read/write/access from the queue.

Comment: Thank you. I am planning to post messages to this queue from an on-prem server. Will IAM role be able to restrict posting of messages from a specific IP address?

Comment: Yes, you could do that (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_deny-ip.html).

Comment: Thanks , what is the difference between this and Security group. I assume it pretty much does the same.

Comment: IAM is Identity and Access Management,  not network and ip oriented like security groups. It's `You use IAM to control who is authenticated (signed in) and authorized (has permissions) to use resources.`. They are really different things. So what I imagine you want is a IAM user with IAM role to access SQS. Then you can use that IAM user credentials from on prem. In addition you can deny queries from certain ips. [What's IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction.html)